# ¿Porque mi variable en node sobreescribe el valor del argumento de esta funcion?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy cumpliendo un reto donde tengo que ordenar un array **sin modificar el array original** entonces se me ocurrio crear una nueva variable que sea igual al argumento, sin embargo me consegui con un comportamiento inespereado (cosa que me dejo pensando como 30 minutos xd) y es que al usar el método **sort()** en mi nueva variable, el valor del argumento de mi función cambia ¿Porque pasa esto? ¿No se supone que al escribir ***let variable = argumento*** la variable copia los valores de lo que este despues del = sin sobreescribir su valor?

```
let argumento = [4,3,5,8]

removeSmallest(argumento)

function removeSmallest(numbers) {
  /**
   * 1 encontrar el number menor LISTO
   * 2 encontrar su index
   */
  if(numbers.length < 1){
    console.log(numbers)
    return numbers
  }

  // Copio al argumento
  const newArray = numbers

  // Esta funcion anonima ordena los elementos de forma ascendente
  newArray.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});

  console.log("Valor de newArray", newArray) // [3,4,5,8]

  console.log('valor de numbers', numbers) // [3,4,5,8]
}
```

Como ven el valor de numbers cambio, cuando deberia ser [4,3,5,8]

Comment: Al final lo solucione usando el spread operator const newArray = [...numbers] pero todavia tengo la duda de porque lo que escribi en mi pregunta

Comment: Los arrays son objetos y lo que Javascript usa no es su "valor "si no una referencia de memoria. Es dicer si lista1 es un objeto y haces lista2 = lista1, ahora lista 2 y lista1 realmente son el mismo objeto, ambas variables guardan la misma dirección de memoria. por tanto lo que hagas con una lo haces con la otra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, javascript no copia el objeto, lo que hace mas bien es simplemente hacer que la nueva variable apunte a la misma dirección de memoria del nuevo objeto, pero esto solo ocurre con objetos `genericos o compuestos`, ya que con tipos `primitivos`, lo que se hace es asignar directamente el valor a la variable y no una referencia al valor, quedando desvinculado totalmente de la variable original y siendo variables totalmente independientes en lo que se refiere a direcciones de memoria.

Tambien tienes que tener en cuenta que lo que pasa es que al estar usando `sort`, `sort` lo que hace es operar sobre el arreglo original, es decir, cambia el contenido del array.

> Sort no devuelve ni opera sobre una copia si no sobre el array
> original, por lo tanto cambia directamente el contenido del array

Te puedes dar cuenta cuando un metodo funciona asi debido a que no requieres usar el operador `=` para que su valor cambie, esto mismo aplica para los metodos `push` y `pop`, los cuales cambian el contenido original del array sin tener que hacer una asignación.

Ahora, con tipos primitivos, nos tendriamos que referir a todo aquello que no sea catalogado como un `object`, en esta categoria entrarian:

1. Numeros enteros
2. Numeros flotantes
3. Strings
4. Booleanos

Cualquier otra cosa que sea un objeto compuesto o que no este en la lista mencionada arriba es tratada como un objeto `compuesto o no primitivo`.

Entonces lo que hace `javascript` es que si se trata de un objeto primitivo guarda directamente el valor sin usar una referencia al objeto original.

Podemos verificar esto si tratamos de usar numero en vez de `arrays`:

```js
let numeroOrg = 5;

function switchNumber(arg){

  let copiaNumero = arg;  //5
  copiaNumero = 20;
  
  console.log(copiaNumero);
  console.log(numeroOrg);
}

switchNumber(numeroOrg);
```

Como vemos se conserva el valor del objeto original, sin embargo apliquemos este mismo ejemplo con un objeto compuesto como lo es un `array`:

```js
const arrOrg = [4, 3, 1, 2]

function delLastFromArray(arg){
  
  let nuevoArr = arg

  nuevoArr.pop();
  
  console.log(nuevoArr);
  console.log(arrOrg);
}

delLastFromArray(arrOrg);
```

Como vemos ha cambiado tanto el valor del objeto original, como de su "copia".

Digo copia entre comillas porque como he dicho anteriormente, enrealidad no estamos asignando una copia del objeto, si no mas bien una referencia al original, que al consultar el "objeto copia", estariamos consultando mas bien el valor del objeto original.

Una forma simple de solucionar tu error y que tu código tenga el comportamiento esperado seria simplemente hacer de verdad una copia del objeto original, el cual no posea sus referencias de memoria.

Para ello hay varias alternativas:

Usar `slice` para forzar la creacion de un nuevo array que posea todos los valores del array original:

```
const newArray = numbers.slice()
```

La desventaja de `slice` es que si el array posee objetos compuestos dentro de el, copiara las referencias de los objetos compuestos tambien.

Usar el operador `spread`, para generar un nuevo array con los valores copiados del array:

```
const newArray = [...numbers]
```

Este metodo tambien tiene el mismo problema descrito en `slice`.

Usar `Object.asign`:

```
const newArray = Object.asign([], numbers)
```

Tambien posee el mismo problema que los 2 anteriores.

Realmente para realizar lo que se conoce como copia profunda, sin que se copien tambien referencias de objetos compuestos habria que mirar alternativas un poco mas pesadas para el performance, pero no hay solución de muy bajos recursos para hacer esto.